# How do i identify/play this file? (It's a WMV inside a MOV?)

Tags: video, codec

I have a file that VLC does not open. It mentioned 'wmv3' so i tried media player with no luck. I use `avicodec` to check which failed.

I also seen some results saying it's a Quicktime file but somehow encoded in WMV (which sounds like nonsense and the poster said he was guessing).

Here's some random text I see inside the file. Perhaps it will help. Does anyone have an idea what this is?

```
ftypqt
qt
moov
lmvhd
Apple Sound Media Handler
:hdlr
mhlrvideappl
Apple Video Media Handler
vmhd
9hdlr
frmaWMA2
ASF
Pwave
dhlralisappl
```

Anyways I want to know how I can see/play the file. I am on Windows 7.

Heres what gspot said ([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erLo7.png)):

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `file` command at hand? Or a hex editor? You should be able to get the [FourCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourcc) out of that thing. Other than that it seems like there's some QuickTime video stuff, so try to rename it to `.mov` (although I have to say I'm guessing too)

Comment: Your guessing @slhck but it is a well educated guess it's possible whoever gave you the file had the wrong extension... particularly if VLC doesn't play it.

Comment: @slhck: yes, I see 'qt' but I also see 'asf'. It would be helpful if the OP clarified where the text he/she pasted came from.

Comment: @horatio Yes, totally agree with that.

Comment: @acidzombie24 Have you tried checking the file with [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) ?

Comment: @slhck, @Kyle, @horatio, @Darius i am surpised gsport worked and avicodec didnt. Ok it appears to be both mov and wmv. so... wtf. How do i play it? The info looks really f'd http://i.imgur.com/erLo7.png

Answer (score 4):

That is a video in the [Windows Media Video 9 (WMV3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC-1) format, which is used in Windows Media Player 9.

You will need the Windows Media Player codecs for that, try the [WMP 9 codec installation package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06fcaab7-dcc9-466b-b0c4-04db144bb601)...

Please note that a [QuickTime File Format (MOV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) is just a [container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29), so it can contain WMP media.

Comment: I couldnt install it. It works on XP and lower. I'm on win with media player 12.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Then you should already have it. Hmm, try to use video editing software like VirtualDub to convert it to a playable file. Seems VLC is incapable of doing this. Combining an open-source video player with a Quicktime container and Windows Media codecs is asking for trouble... ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net) - it does a good job of showing you everything about media files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems WMV video and WMA audio data are placed in the MOV/MP4 file.
That is, file format (container format) is MOV, video codec (compression method) is WMV, and audio codec is WMA. It's very rare and possible non-standard format, I think.

Have test with [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/), it has better support for MOV/MP4 than VLC.

Try reformat into AVI or WMV with [ffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/FFmpeg/git-N-28849-ga82cfad/FFmpeg-git-N-28849-ga82cfad.7z/download):
ffmpeg.exe -i 'your file' -acodec copy -vcodec copy new_file.avi